# How to create a new instance of a class in Processing

Tags: arrays, class, instance, processing

Im working in Processing and I am trying to create a new instance of the class Place in my code. Place(x, y) puts a new "turret" somewhere on my grid. I created an array of size 10 and assigned that to "turret". I want it to make a new one when I hit "q". I run my program and when I try pressing 'q' it crashes and says "Null Pointer exception, and highlights the line show below with a // comment.

```
PImage grid;
Place[] turret;
int g=0;
int i;

void setup()
{ 
  size(1501, 811);
  background(255);
  grid = loadImage("Grid.png");
  turret = new Place[10];
}
void draw()
{
  image(grid, 0, 0, 1503, 811);
  if (keyPressed)
    if (key == 'q')
    {
      turret[i] = new Place(1157, 405);  // Hitting 'q' on the keyboard causes a Null Pointer exception that points to this line
      i++;
      g=1;
    }
  if(g==1)
  {
    turret[i].circle();
    turret[i].keyPressed();
  }
}

class Place
{ 
  int xPos, yPos;
  Place(int x, int y)
  {
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
  }

  void circle()
  {
    ellipse(xPos, yPos, 30, 30);
  }

  void move(int amount, char xy)
  {
    frameRate(10);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(xPos, yPos);
    if (xy == 'x')
      xPos+=amount;
    if (xy == 'y')
      yPos+=amount;
    circle();
    popMatrix();
  }

  int v=0;
  void keyPressed()
  {
    if (keyPressed)
    {
      if (key == 'd' && v==0)
        move(30, 'x');
      if (key == 'a' && v==0)
        move(-30, 'x');
      if (key == 's' && v==0)
        move(30, 'y');
      if (key == 'w' && v==0)
        move(-30, 'y');
      if (key == 'x' && v==0)
      {
        v=1;
        fill(0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that `draw()` is a loop that, by deafult, is called 60 times each second. So checking for `keyPressed` or `mousePressed` inside draw is kind of imprecise. See for yoursef:

int i; void draw(){if(keyPressed)i++; println(i);}

as fast as you press a key it will increase `i` more than one each press, and worse, differents amount each time.

So you better use the call back function `keyPressed()` instead

```java
int i; void draw(){println(i);} void keyPressed(){i++;}
```

Another thing is that the logic, I think, is a bit weird. Cause of the way you are incrementing i...

```java
// i = 0
 if (keyPressed)
    if (key == 'q')
    {
     // you add a turret at index 0
      turret[i] = new Place(1157, 405);  // Hitting 'q' on the keyboard causes a Null Pointer exception that points to this line

// here ideally i = 1
 i++;
      g=1;
    }
  if(g==1)
  {

   // here you call circle and keyPressed on an empty slot in the array
   // turret [1] have no instance... hence the NPE
    turret[i].circle();
    turret[i].keyPressed();
  }
}
```

and then `i` is never reset, so it keeps going beyond your array length...

For lists that are dynamically modified during runtime, I prefer to use Lists, like ArrayList. But you can do it with an array also. You will then have to check and limit the "iterator" to the occupied slots in the array.

Here is what I think you are looking for using ArrayList:
Probably the same thing about keyPressed is true for the key handling inside the class:

```java
ArrayList<Place> turret = new ArrayList<Place>();

void setup()
{ 
  size(1501, 811);
  background(255);
}
void draw()
{
  //if the list is not empty
  if (turret.size() > 0) {
    //it could be a regular for loop also
    for (Place p : turret) {
      p.circle();
      p.keyHandle();
    }
  }
}


void keyPressed(){
  // you can add as much Places as you want :)
  if(key == 'q'){
    turret.add(new Place(int(random(width)), int(random(height))));
  }
}

class Place
{ 
  int xPos, yPos;
  Place(int x, int y)
  {
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
  }

  void circle()
  {
    ellipse(xPos, yPos, 30, 30);
  }

  void move(int amount, char xy)
  {
    frameRate(10);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(xPos, yPos);
    if (xy == 'x')
      xPos+=amount;
    if (xy == 'y')
      yPos+=amount;
    circle();
    popMatrix();
  }

  int v=0;
  // you don't want to override processing keyPressed
  // unles you register it, so I'm changing the name
  void keyHandle()
  {
    if (keyPressed)
    {
      if (key == 'd' && v==0)
        move(30, 'x');
      if (key == 'a' && v==0)
        move(-30, 'x');
      if (key == 's' && v==0)
        move(30, 'y');
      if (key == 'w' && v==0)
        move(-30, 'y');
      if (key == 'x' && v==0)
      {
        v=1;
        fill(0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I really would go with ArrayList, but here an example of same thing with array.

```java
PImage grid;
Place[] turret;
int nextInsert = 0;

void setup()
{ 
  size(1501, 811);
  background(255);
  //grid = loadImage("Grid.png");
  turret = new Place[10];
}
void draw()
{

  for(int i =0 ; i < turret.length; i++){ 
    if(turret[i] != null){
      turret[i].circle();
      turret[i].keyHandle();
    }

  }

}

void keyPressed(){
  if(key == 'q'){
    if(nextInsert < turret.length){
      turret[nextInsert] = new Place(int(random(width)), int(random(height)));
      nextInsert++;
    }
  }
}


class Place
{ 
  int xPos, yPos;
  Place(int x, int y)
  {
    xPos = x;
    yPos = y;
  }

  void circle()
  {
    ellipse(xPos, yPos, 30, 30);
  }

  void move(int amount, char xy)
  {
    frameRate(10);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(xPos, yPos);
    if (xy == 'x')
      xPos+=amount;
    if (xy == 'y')
      yPos+=amount;
    circle();
    popMatrix();
  }

  int v=0;
  void keyHandle()
  {
    if (keyPressed)
    {
      if (key == 'd' && v==0)
        move(30, 'x');
      if (key == 'a' && v==0)
        move(-30, 'x');
      if (key == 's' && v==0)
        move(30, 'y');
      if (key == 'w' && v==0)
        move(-30, 'y');
      if (key == 'x' && v==0)
      {
        v=1;
        fill(0);
      }
    }
  }
}
```